# Python Script To Pull All Metadata & Xobjects from PDF

Tags: python, pdf

Our team is self taught by google and youtube. We are trying to pull ALL metadata out of a PDF to include all xobjects. We have found what we are looking for by using the internal PDF structure report and looking at the Resources where there is "pattern" as this is what we would really like to locate and what page it is on. We have tried to use pdfminer, but this has not returned what we need.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: *"Our team is self taught by google and youtube."* - I would propose you add studying the pdf specification to that list. Adobe published a copy of ISO 32000-1 on their web site (Google for pdf32000) for free download, so there is no excuse for not studying it. That being said, you should indeed make your question much more concrete, focusing on a specific problem.